# Prove that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n}$ is uniformly convergente by variable change

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

*Prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n}$$
is uniformly convergente in $[\delta,2\pi-\delta]$ with $\delta \in(0,\pi)$*

It could be proved by the  Dirichelt's criterion; but if we want to solve it by variable change, I get a problem.

If we denote $\omega = e^{ix}$, then
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\omega^n}{n}$$
that is convergente in $\bar D(0,\delta)$ with $\delta<1$. How I can see the radio is of convergence for $x$?

Comment: [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) or consider  $\frac{d}{d\omega}\sum_{n=0}^N \omega^n$ or for a rational $x$ group the terms to get an alternated series, and try to extend the result to $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}$. maybe a change of variable could also lead to a Riemann sum + a negligible $\epsilon$ (and the result would follow from integrating by part the obtained integral)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be enlightening to switch to a complex variable. Thus let $z\in
\mathbb{C}$ with $Imz>0$. Then
\begin{equation*}
I(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}e^{inz}
\end{equation*}
converges and
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{z}I(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(e^{iz})^{n}=\frac{e^{iz}}{1-e^{iz}}
\end{equation*}
We see that this expression is analytic except in the poles, defined by
\begin{equation*}
e^{iz}=e^{i(z+k2\pi )}=1\Rightarrow z_{k}=k2\pi ,\;k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots
\end{equation*}
Formally
\begin{equation*}
I(z)=\ln (1-e^{iz})
\end{equation*}
but we have to be careful with the logarithm. Outside the poles we can let $
Imz$ tend to $0$, in particular for $x=Rez\in (0,2\pi )$

Answer (score 0):

The series converges uniformly for $|\omega|\le\delta<1$. You can't recuperate an interval of convergence for $x$ since $|e^{ix}|=1$.

Comment: Suppose another case where I can recuperate de interval of convergence $(-R,R)$. We can say that R is the radio is of convergence of the original serie?

Comment: The concept of radius of convergence applies to power series. The original series is a Fourier series.